# How can I pass 18 variables into one function to validate my PHP/MySQL Interaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, validation, code-injection

I have a profile page on my website where can you login and update your account details, such as: First Name, Last Name, Username, Company, Address Line 1 etc.

See code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $AccountID = $row["AccountID"];
        $FName = $row["FName"];
        $LName = $row["LName"];
        $Username = $row["Username"];
        $Company = $row["Company"];
        $AddressL1 = $row["AddressL1"];
        $AddressL2 = $row["AddressL2"];
        $Town = $row["Town"];
        $County = $row["County"];
        $PostCode = $row["PostCode"];
        $Password = $row["Password"];
        $DFName = $row["DFName"];
        $DLName = $row["DLName"];
        $DAddressL1 = $row["DAddressL1"];
        $DAddressL2 = $row["DAddressL2"];
        $DTown = $row["DTown"];
        $DCounty = $row["DCounty"];
        $DPostCode = $row["DPostCode"];
    }

    if ($_SESSION['login_user']) {
```

If they are logged in then it'll echo out each value to the input fields and you can change and update them as you will...

Rather than write out

```
$login_session = stripslashes($login_session);
$login_session = mysql_real_escape_string($login_session);
$login_session = trim($login_session);
```

For every single variable, what is the best option?

Comment: write a function that does `stripslashes`, `mysql_real_escape_string` and `trim` could be a good starting point

Comment: I think this is best for codereview.stackexchange personally, and also, just a pointer, avoid using mysql_* functionality as it is depreciated and won't be around much longer, look into mysqli (pretty much the same as mysql_* but better) or PDO :)

Comment: @c.bear, I was working on that as you said it!

Comment: @SamSwift I'm afraid this would probably be off-topic for CodeReview. We are purely for reviewing Code that is already written and working. Advice on feature requests is not something we do.

Comment: @Zak, good to know, thank you for clarifying that :)

Comment: @SamSwift There's some nuances to it. For instance, if the OP wrote out that code and posted it for review, an answer could, quite possibly, include a better way of doing it. But the key point is that the code must actually be written (and working) in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something such as:

```
function makeSafe($var)
{
    $return = stripslashes($var);
    $return = mysql_real_escape_string($return);
    $return = trim($return);
    return $return;
}

$login_session = makeSafe($login_session);
```

This will avoid the many lines of code on one page and avoid duplicate code

And as I said in my comment, try to avoid mysql_* functionality and replace it with either mysqli or PDO